Vulkan : app work fine on RenderDoc but not with Stand-Alone execution
I recently added dephTesting on my Vulkan application, but geometries are displayed only when launched from RenderDoc. Validation layers are activated, and there is no error log.
I precise that the problem occure when i activate depthTesting with VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS.
I'd like to have some clues as to what the problem might be.

You don't give a lot to go on, so I'm grasping at straws here. Note that RenderDoc disables some layers and enables others, so that may be one reason for the behaviour you experience. Some information about that is printed on the std::out, so have a look. Apart from that, make sure the shader is called. Vulkan has a print function you can use to do that: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/blob/main/docs/debug_printf.md. Finally check that the geometry is rendered at all, e.g. if the shader works, make it output a solid colour that sets it apart from the background.
